# mogenerator missing in Xcode 5.1

Tags: xcode

I cloned the DuckDuckGo open source iOS project on my machine. When I compile the code I got an Shell Script Invocation Error from Xcode:

```
/Users/nirbhay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DuckDuckGo-fbzkqkdplgwdyzbcwxtfiydcqkfj/Build/Intermediates/DuckDuckGo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mogenerator.build/Script-5BFF24C116F77F0700844D3B.sh: 
line 3: /usr/local/bin/mogenerator: No such file or directory
```

I installed mogenerator from a DMG. It seems the mogenerator was put into the /usr/bin/ directory instead of /usr/local/bin/ directory where Xcode expected it. So I manually created the bin directory in local/ and copied the mogenerator file there. The code compiles now.

I am not an expert so what I did seems like a hack to me. Can anybody tell me why this happened in the first place and if there was a right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**mogenerator** is called from a shell script in the "Build Phases" of the target. In your case, it seems that mogenerator is called with an absolute path

```
/usr/local/bin/mogenerator --model ...
```

If mogenerator is installed in /usr/bin/ then you can change that line to

```
/usr/bin/mogenerator --model ...
```

or simply

```
mogenerator --model ...
```

because /usr/bin/ is in the default search path of Xcode.

Comment: So you mean that the issue is in the project's settings. The path for mogenerator is hardcoded to a different location than the where it is installed by default?

Comment: @Nirbhay: Yes, exactly. (But the default install location may depend on *how* it is installed.)

Comment: I see. So it may be different, for example, if i had installed it via homebrew instead of DMG. Interesting. Thanks this really cleared things up.